# Jquery help needed, trying to get a specific div with an id that is dynamically generated to toggle

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm a newbie with jquery so I'm still trying to test things out.

With php I'm generating div's with a an id,

example :

```
<div id="myid-1"></div> 
<div id="myid-2"></div>
```

and so on. if I click on a link I need to toggle that id. Here is my jquery code

```
$("#sublike").live('click', function(){

    $(this).find(div[id^='sublike-form-']).toggle();

});
```

I'm doing something wrong, as firebug is saying undefined.

What is the correct why of findinf a dynamic div id to toggle it?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Post some html markup for your sceneario

Comment: What's the actual id of the div you want to toggle?

Comment: Which is undefined? `$(this)` or the result of `.find()`? If you place your calls on different lines, you'll be able to add breakpoints to different methods calls (see code formatting in my answer for an example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing some quotes:

```
$("#sublike").live('click', function(){
    $(this).find("div[id^='sublike-form-']").toggle();
});
```

Also in your HTML example, the ids are "myid-1", "myid-2, yet your jQuery is looking for Ids beggining with "sublike-form-".

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the quotes and so on :) I've changed it to the following: $("div").find("div[id^='sublike-form-']").toggle(); It works but I now all elements get opened with that match on the click event.

Comment: No worries. Could you accept this answer if it worked for you? It would mean people would be more likely to help you in future. Also, all elements matching the ID you put in your selector will open. If you don't want this behaviour you'd need to modify your selector. It may be worth asking for that in a new question if you're having problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [event target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) rather than `this` and putting your selector in quotes in your `.find()`

```
$("#sublike")
    .live('click', function(event){

        $(event.target)
            .find('div[id^="sublike-form-"]')
            .toggle();  
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the url to the event.target info this helped me out a bit :)

Comment: You're welcome. Those API pages are really useful. Check out http://www.amazon.co.uk/jQuery-Action-Second-Bear-Bibeault/dp/1935182323/ too, it's fantastic (and has a free ebook with it too). Also, welcome to the site. If you find an answer or question useful, click up-vote to share the love.